# "this" inside object

Tags: javascript, object, this

I'm trying to calculate a proportional height (while excluding a static height element) from a width that gets passed in via a request (defaults to 560).

However, `wF.h` evaluates to `NaN`. If I replace `this.w` with 560 it works, but not when trying to reference the `w` property of `wF`.

```
var wF = {
       w : 560,
       h : (312 - 42) / (560 / this.w) + 42
};
```

What gives?

I refuse to use two plain vars in succession, because I'm trying to get nice code out of JS.

**Update:**

Thanks to everyone who helped explain and solve my problem. I guess i'll just have to get used to that. I'll be setting the object up in stages to get on with the project, even though it still annoys me slightly ;). I found and read a nice article on the topic for anyone who stumbles upon similar issues: http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/

Comment: what version of ecmascript? i dont think this is javascript

Comment: var wF = {---} does the same thing.

Comment: i am happy that you noticed. any initialization as object needs `new` (your constructor). and so your object declaration is wrong

Comment: while you are technically right it doesn't really relate to my problem.

Comment: i thought you said *nice* code :)

Comment: yeah, i've updated it to simplify the issue. i want nice code, but so far from the answers and my own research it looks like i can either do it procedually or encapsulate the properties somewhat messy. i'm rather fresh to JS obviously, but this is awfully daunting :(

Comment: @mhe: It's just a consequence of using a basic object notation. Its not optimised for properties at declaration to be functions of one another.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

```
// Your code
var wF = {
       w : 560,
       h : (312 - 42) / (560 / this.w) + 42
};
```

---

#### `this` isn't what you think it is

Javascript has no block scope, only function scope: `this` inside the definition for `wF` does *not* refer to `wF`.

(And so `this.w`, whatever `this` is, is likely `undefined`. Dividing by `undefined` yields `NaN`.)

So then you might try:

```
// Let's not use `this`
var wF = {
       w : 560,
       h : (312 - 42) / (560 / wF.w) + 42
};
```

---

#### You haven't finished defining the object yet

However, you're *still defining the object* where you attempt to use `wF.w`: [it's not ready for that yet](http://jsfiddle.net/xTY5n/).

---

#### Solution

So, yes, you will have to use two variables... or set up the object in stages:

```
// We can't even use `wF`; split up the property definitions
var wF = {};
wF.w = 560;
wF.h = (312 - 42) / (560 / wF.w) + 42;
```

Comment: But this is also not a solution, because If you will change the old var to let or const, you will receive the error, that you are using variable, which is not initialized yet :-(

Comment: ...the solution is to use for example class, but really I must use this complicated way?     class X {
        public static w = 560;
        public static h = (312 - 42) / (560 / X.w) + 42;
    }

Answer (score 48):

Hi just redefine your second property as a function object and it will work. I think it is possible to access the context of the calling object from within a function

```
var wF = {
    w : 560,
    h : function() { return (312 - 42) / (560 / this.w) + 42; }
};

alert(wF.h())
```

Comment: I could not get this to work with arrow function, but this did work!

Comment: It will not work with arrow function, as the arrow function does not have its own `this` - it uses `this` from parent function context.

Comment: You actually can get the arrow function to work: 

{ 
  matches: {
      played: 5,
      won: 4,
      draw: 0,
      lost: 1
    },
    points: () => (this.matches.won * 3) + (this.matches.draw * 1)
} . This works inside an array of objects, this isn't evaluated until you call the function.

Comment: @thatgibbyguy. I haven't tried with an array member. thanks for sharing! I learned something :-)

Comment: @thatgibbyguy I don't think that works at all. Arrow functions do not have their own this => see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Arrow_functions_used_as_methods 
In your ex the this.matches.won and this.matches.draw will be taken from window/global object. So, say you have: var test = { matches: { played: 5, won: 4, draw: 0, lost: 1 }, points: () => (this.matches.won * 3) + (this.matches.draw * 1) } , calling test.points() throws error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'won' of undefined"

Comment: change it to `get h() { ... }` and you may still use `alert(wF.h)`

Answer (score 3):

The `this` keyword refers to the calling context, not an object.

You need to do this in two steps like so:

```
var wF = { w: 560 };
wF.h = (312 - 42) / (560 / wF.w) + 42;
```

Comment: you are right of course, and at least it will build object properties instead of plain variables, but it's got me really frustrated that i have to do this procedually :D

Comment: If you prefer the OO way, then create an object with getters and setters. This way you can use this.getW() in the definition of the getH() function.

Comment: And vastly overcomplicate your code. Potentially.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to wrap the {...} in an Object().  It is already an object literal.

`this` doesn't operate inside the object literal, it will point to the object that the function is currently running in so:

```
function fn() {
   var wF = { w : 560, h : (312 - 42) / (560 / this.w) + 42 };
}

fn();
```

will cause `this` to point to the `window` object.

EDIT: Previous code was not intended to be an answer, just a demonstration of what `this` is.  Another possiblity would be to use a function that takes the width as an argument:

```
function getObject(width) {
    width = width || 560; //Default value to 560
    return { w: width, h : (312 - 42) / (560 / width) + 42 };
}

var wF = getObject(); //To get the default value, or specify a width otherwise.
```

Comment: @AlienWebguy Right, because it's trying to divide by `this.w`, which is `window.w`, which is undefined.

Comment: This is a good partial explanation of the problem, but there is no solution here.

Comment: This answer is unhelpful - please test your code before posting it.

Comment: @TeslaNick: It's not meant as an answer, apparently. It's a demonstration of why `this` is wrong inside the object literal.

Comment: @Nick Tomalak is correct.  I added some code that does work.

Answer (score -1):

When you use this in a JSON object declaration, it points to the current instance.

You can try this code in your console to understand it better:

```
Object({ w : 560, h : (312 - 42) / (560 / function(e){console.log(e);return e.w;}(this)) + 42 });
```

Comment: This code proves that `this` is `window` because, no, it does _not_ "point to the current instance" at all.

Comment: Because you are running it on window context. I mean when he used this.w, this doesn´t point to wf.

Comment: Also that is not JSON.