# Javascript object literal, how to use 'this' to reference a variable in the object

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, object-literal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“this” inside object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043509/this-inside-object)

I'm trying to make an object literal for a couple of default options for a jQuery plugin that I'm working on:

```
  var defaults = {

            r: 5,
            top: this.r,
            bottom: this.r,
            topleft: this.top,
            topright: this.top,
            bottomleft: this.bottom,
            bottomright: this.bottom


        };
```

when I reference the `defaults.top` it is `undefined`

anything I can do to make this work? Or perhaps a different approach? I need it to be an object literal.

Added:

It is (`default` object), the way it's cascading down as you can see, was intended to be some what of a short hand technique. For example, if you would like to define all corners to be the same, you would use `{r: 5}` but if you want the top and bottom to be different `{top: 5, bottom: 1}` again, individually `{topleft: 5, topright:2, bottomleft: 3, bottomright:19 }` I apologize for not making this clear, but am very grateful for your answers.

ANSWERED: This is what I ended up doing

```
if(o.topleft == undefined || o.topright == undefined || o.bottomleft == undefined || o.bottomright == undefined){
                if(o.top == undefined || o.bottom == undefined){
                    if(o.r == undefined){
                        o.topleft = 5;
                        o.topright = 5;
                        o.bottomleft = 5;
                        o.bottomright = 5;
                    }else{
                        o.topleft = o.r;
                        o.topright = o.r;
                        o.bottomleft = o.r;
                        o.bottomright = o.r;  
                    }
                }
                else{
                    o.topleft = o.top;
                    o.topright = o.top;
                    o.bottomleft = o.bottom;
                    o.bottomright = o.bottom;
                }
            }
```

supper sloppy, but hey it worked! Thank you for all your help! I chose the answer because that explanation led me to do it this way!

Comment: You need it to be an object literal, or you need it to be an object?

Comment: You know, if it works better with an object I guess it can work, but I would like it to be simple enough to do something like this `$(selector).myPlugin({r:10});` or `$(selector).myPlugin({top:10, bottom: 5});`

Comment: you will find this useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/7043822/205585

Comment: **@Senthil Kumar**, exactly! -> `var def = {}; def.r = 5; def.top = def.r`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"when I reference the* `defaults.top` *it is* `undefined`*"*

That's because `this` doesn't refer to the object you're creating, it is the `this` from whatever scope that code is running in.

Object literal syntax does not allow you to set values by referencing other properties in the same object - the object doesn't exist yet. You *can* reference other variables or functions declared *before* the object literal. So if you need all the properties to be the same like in your example then you can do this:

```
var val = 5,
    defaults = {
            r: val,
            top: val,
            bottom: val,
            topleft: val,
            topright: val,
            bottomleft: val,
            bottomright: val
    };
```

Or create some of the properties with an object literal and set the rest afterwards:

```
var defaults = {
        r : 5
    };

defaults.top = defaults.bottom = defaults.r;
defaults.topleft = defaults.topright = defaults.top;
// etc
```

Obviously the latter is more suited to setting some properties to one value and other properties to another value. (Though again in your example all properties are the same.)

Either way gives you the same object in the end (an object literal is just a shortcut way to create objects).

> *" I would like it to be simple enough to do something like this* `$(selector).myPlugin({r:10});` *or* `$(selector).myPlugin({top:10, bottom: 5});` *"*

Well you can still *call* the plugin with an object literal as a parameter. But the `defaults` object (which I assume is defined inside the plugin) can be defined using other techniques.

Comment: It is (`default` object), the way it's cascading down as you can see, was intended to be some what of a short hand technique. For example, if you would like to define all corners to be the same, you would use `{r: 5}` but if you want the top and bottom to be different `{top: 5, bottom: 1}` again, individually `{topleft: 5, topright:2, bottomleft: 3, bottomright:19 }` I apologize for not making this clear, but am very grateful for your answer. You say there are other ways?

Comment: I figured you wanted a cascading effect, so I tried to show that in my second example. _"You say there are other ways?"_ - Well other than the two techniques shown in my question, you could use a [constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_a_constructor_function). You don't necessarily have to do all of an object's properties in the same way, you can mix and match. (E.g., start with a constructor function, then add some extra properties, then use [`$.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) to mix in an object literal...)