# How do self referenced objects work in JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set up a javascript object with one of it's items being a function. I am doing a little bit of self reference and it is not working.

```
var onTimePoints = function($a, $b, $c, $lifeotr){

    $var1 = ($b - $a) / $c;
    $var2 = ($lifeotr - $a) / $var1;
    if($var2>$c)
    {
    $var2 = $c;
    }
    if($var2<0)
    {
    $var2 = 0;
    }
    $var2 = Math.round($var2);
    return $var2;
}
var lifeData ={
      min: 25000,
      max: 65000,
      otr: 56426,
      maxPoints:100,
      otp: onTimePoints(25000, 65000, 100, 56426),
      test: function(){
        alert(this.min);
      }
}
```

When I do `conosle.log(lifeData.otp)` it works.

When I replace the hard coded numbers with `this.min`, `this.max`, etc... it doesn't work.

Here is an example of what doesn't work:

```
var lifeData ={
  min: 25000,
  max: 65000,
  otr: 56426,
  maxPoints:100,
  otp: onTimePoints(this.min, this.max, this.maxPoints, this.otr),
  test: function(){
    alert(this.min);
  }
}
```

In this case `console.log(lifeData.otp)` returns `NaN`.

I am sure that I am just overlooking something. Appreciate if you know the issue.

Comment: I deleted my original comment but then I realized I was right :-)  The value of `this` has nothing whatsoever to do with an under-construction object literal.  It has to do solely with function invocation context.  Basically there's no direct way to do what you're doing in JavaScript. You have to use a separate statement.

Comment: When I alert this.min it alerts 25000. I am assuming that this.min is the same as saying lifeData.min

Comment: `this` is `window`, not `lifeData`.

Comment: It is, but that's *inside* that "test" function call.  When you call `lifeData.test()`, it's that function call itself that ensures that `this` inside the function is set to refer to the "lifeData" object. However, that's *not* the case in the midst of the object literal that initializes the object.  In that context, `this` has a value determined by the context of that `var` declaration.

Comment: @My_Boon No, it's not working.  Try calling `lifeData.otp;` and you'll see that you get a `NaN` back.

Comment: oops. formula is a placeholder variable that I have set earlier in my script. Forgot to take it out before I posted. I will fix it.

Comment: Now another possibility is to make the "otp" property be a *wrapper*: `otp: function() { onTimePoints(this.min, this.maxPoints, ... ); }`

Comment: possible duplicate of ["this" inside object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043509/this-inside-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you're trying to do.

Consider:

```
var lifeData ={
  min: 25000,
  max: 65000,
  otr: 56426,
  maxPoints:100,
  otp: onTimePoints(25000, 65000, 100, 56426),
  otNewcomm: formula,
  test: function(){
    alert(this.min);
  }
}
```

or

```
var min = 25000;
var max = 65000;
var otr = 56426;
var maxPoints = 100;
var lifeData ={
  min: min,
  max: max,
  otr: otr,
  maxPoints: maxPoints,
  otp: onTimePoints(min, max, maxPoints, otr),
  otNewcomm: formula,
  test: function(){
    alert(this.min);
  }
}
```

or

```
function lifeData(min, max, otr, maxPoints)
{
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
    this.otr = otr;
    this.maxPoints = maxPoints;
    this.otp = onTimePoints(min, max, maxPoints, otr);
    ...
}
var lifeDataInstance = new lifeData(25000, 65000, 56426, 100);
```

Comment: Or possibly the "otp" property could be a function wrapper around a call to "onTimePoints".

Comment: The last chunk is what I am using because i am going to be creating a new instance every time an event is fired. It is to refresh the view with the correct numbers. Seems like the best solution.

Answer (score 5):

You will get a lot of tutorials to understand this, but here I am trying to illustrate it using a few lines of code. In firebug console or Chrome console do the following

1. enter `this` and press enter

   **> Window** // Now it is global scope
2. Run the following code

   ```
   this.a = 500;
   this.b = 600;
   ```
3. Now run the following code;

   ```
   var MyObject = {
       a: 20,
       b: 40,
       sum: this.a + this.b,
       getSum: function(){
           return this.a + this.b;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Now run the following

   ```
      MyObject.sum
   ```

   **> 1100** // because `MyObect` is declared in global scope and in the expression `sum:this.a+this.b` `this`  is Window object. so `sum: 400 + 500`
5. Now run

   ```
      MyObject.getSum();
   ```

   **> 60** // because `getSum` is a method of `MyObject`. And when invoked like `MyObject.getSum()` inside the `getSum` `this` will be `MyObject`. so it returns `20 + 40`

Comment: a small correction. it should not be 900 it should be 1100 `500+600`.