# Console logging "this" returns "null"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browserify, babeljs, reactjs-flux

I am trying to create a flux store for a React app I am building. I am using an object-assign polyfill npm package and Facebook's Flux library.

Initially I was getting the error "Cannot read property '_data' of null' error in the console which was refering to `var currIds = this._data.map(function(m){return m.id;});`. That method is currently the only one being called directly.  I then did `console.log(this)` which returned "null".

I find this strange. What is going on?

My code:

```
var Assign = require('object-assign');
var EventEmitterProto = require('events').EventEmitter.prototype;
var CHANGE_EVENT = 'CHANGE';

var StoreMethods = {

init: function() {},
set: function (arr) {
console.log(this);
    var currIds = this._data.map(function(m){return m.id;});

    arr.filter(function (item){
      return currIds.indexOf(item.id) === -1;
    }).forEach(this.add.bind(this));

},
add: function(item){
  console.log(this);
    this._data.push(item);
},
all: function() {
    return this._data;
},
get: function(id){
   return this._data.filter(function(item){
       return item.cid === id;
   })[0];
},
addChangeListener: function(fn) {
    this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, fn);
},
removeChangeListener: function(fn) {
    this.removeListener(CHANGE_EVENT, fn);
 },
 emitChange: function() {
    this.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
 },
 bind: function(actionType, actionFn) {
    if(this.actions[actionType]){
        this.actions[actionType].push(actionFn);
    } else {
        this.actions[actionType] = [actionFn];
    }
}
};

exports.extend = function(methods) {
var store = {
_data: [],
actions: {}
};

Assign(store, EventEmitterProto, StoreMethods, methods);
store.init();

require('../dispatcher').register(function(action){
   if(store.actions[action.actionType]){
       store.actions[action.actionType].forEach(function(fn){
        fn.call(null, action.data);
       })   
   }
  });

  return store;
 };
```

Comment: Because javascript implements the scope in a functional way, only functions create new scopes.

Comment: Likely duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043509/this-inside-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't `see` where set is called, however your `this` can be `null` if the function is invoked through `call` (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)) or `apply`, and your first argument is `null`.
This also happens in your `require.register` callback:

```
fn.call(null, action.data) //First parameter is your 'this'.
```

Comment: Changing the first parameter (context) of .call seems to have worked. Thank you! :-)