# How can i use this.state within this.state in constructor?

Tags: reactjs

I'm use state in this.state in constructor. how can i use immediately state after declaration?

```
    constructor() {
        super(...arguments);
        this.state = {
            client: null,
            client1: this.state.client,
        }
   }
```

Comment: Why would you need to do this? Any scenario?

Comment: Can't you just use `null` again?

Comment: @KaungMyatLwin i need to use this scenario to assign dynamic array value to chart options. i retrieve one by one value from AWS query and update value of line chart options

Answer (score 3):

You can have your state in an object outside the assignment itself and then assigning the state to that object modifying whatever data you may want:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  const state = { client: null }
  this.state = { ...state, client1: state.client };
}
```

Check this one out:
["this" inside object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043509/this-inside-object)

Answer (score 0):

you could do:

```
constructor() {
    super(...arguments);
    this.state = {
        client: null,    
    }
    this.state.client1 = this.state.client;
}
```

Even though, you could also assign `null` to `client1`, as @zmag mentioned, if you always assign `null` to `this.state.client`