# why I could use variable before declared in function

Tags: javascript

in this code snippet, I could not use obj before declaration

```js
 const obj = {
     value : 10,
     x : obj
}
```

while here I could

```js
 const obj = {
     func : () => console.log(obj.value),
     value : 10,
}
obj.func();
```

How could the second compiles but the first fail?

actually, I wonder why any of them compiles since I used `obj` before it was instantiated, as I understand (I may be wrong) first the right side first evaluated, and then assign the result
to the variable(`obj`)

Comment: The `obj` reference in the second code block will not be evaluated until that `func()` is actually called. At declaration time, no reference is made.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, this is a JS hoisting and scope issue. I believe the problem lies in the fact that `obj` inside your first code snippet is being called while also being declared, which causes the error. Conversely, the second code snippet keeps a function inside the scope of `obj`, so when hoisted, the variable const is given a value of an obj with a function that hasn't been called yet, and a value. So when calling the function with `obj.func()`, it's doing so AFTER the variable is given a full value.

[Better explanation if mine made no sense at all.](https://codeburst.io/hoist-your-knowledge-of-javascript-hoisting-59b73124b430)

Alternatively, you could try setting up the variable in stages, i.e:

```js
const obj = {}
obj.value = 10;
obj.x = obj.value
console.log(obj)
```

[Better Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043509/this-inside-object)

It really depends on what your intent is, but to my knowledge the concept is the same.

[Extended reading on JS engine, the runtime, and the call stack.](https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-does-javascript-actually-work-part-1-b0bacc073cf)