# how to call function inside object

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object as follows

```
var shop = {
    costPrice: function() {
        return 100;
    },
    sellingPrice: function() {
        var calculateProfit = function() {
            return this.costPrice() * 0.2;
        }

        return this.costPrice() + calculateProfit();
    }
};

console.log(shop.sellingPrice());
```

But this gives me the following error

```
objects.html:16 Uncaught TypeError: this.costPrice is not a function
    at calculateProfit (objects.html:16)
    at Object.sellingPrice (objects.html:19)
    at objects.html:22
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong as `costPrice` is a function

Comment: I think that you can not (to be verified). You should declare the object as a class instance so that you could use something like `this.costPrice()`

Comment: You can make calculateProfit an arrow function.  `var calculateProfit = () => this.costPrice() * 0.2;`

Comment: `this` is then the object itself? Didn't know that, that's nice!

Comment: @GuillaumeMunsch, sort of.  Please check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095710/methods-in-es6-objects-using-arrow-functions for more details on what `this` means in an arrow function..

Comment: Ty! Just went through this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/7043822/3683576 :)

Comment: @Wyck can you explain why using the arrow function for `calculateProfit` works? Is it because in arrow function `this` will refer to the object and not the `costPrice` function?

Comment: @ThatRandomDeveloper, that has been explained elsewhere. e.g. [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this):  _ES2015 introduced arrow functions which don't provide their own `this` binding (it retains the `this` value of the enclosing lexical context)._

Answer (score 3):

`calculateProfit` must be an arrow function

```
var shop = {
            costPrice : function() {
                return 100;
            },
            sellingPrice : function() {
                var calculateProfit = () => {
                    return this.costPrice() * 0.2;
                }

                return this.costPrice() + calculateProfit();
            }
        };

console.log(shop.sellingPrice());
```

Comment: This works. But can you explain as to why this works?

Comment: Because when using `function`,  `this` refers to the `window` object but when using an arrow function `this` refers to its current surrounding scope.

Comment: @ThatRandomDeveloper, FYI _why it works_ is explained in detail in [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#arrow_functions).

Answer (score 1):

Try changing these functions to be arrows:

```js
var shop = {
            costPrice : function() {
                return 100;
            },
            sellingPrice : function() {
                var calculateProfit = () => {
                    return this.costPrice() * 0.2;
                }

                return this.costPrice() + calculateProfit();
            }
        };

console.log(shop.sellingPrice());
```

Comment: In that case, `this` will refer to whatever "this" was in scope before `shop` was defined. Try changing `sellingPrice` to be a regular `function`

Comment: Yup, just after adding comment I realised that only `calculateProfit` should be arrow, I will fix that :D

Answer (score 1):

```js
var shop = {
    costPrice: function() {
        return 100;
    },
    sellingPrice: function() {
        var calculateProfit = () => this.costPrice() * 0.2;

        return this.costPrice() + calculateProfit();
    }
};

console.log(shop.sellingPrice());
```

Comment: Valid, but you offer no explanation of what you've done or why it helps.