# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '2') happens while using an object method on arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, variables, javascript-objects

i was learning array destruction from objects and then it should return two values as the order function says but it doesnt

```
const restaurant = {
    name: 'Classico Italiano',
    location: 'Via Angelo Tavanti 23, Firenze, Italy',
    categories: ['Italian', 'Pizzeria', 'Vegetarian', 'Organic'],
    starterMenu: ['Focaccia', 'Bruschetta', 'Garlic Bread', 'Caprese Salad'],
    mainMenu: ['Pizza', 'Pasta', 'Risotto'],
    order: (starterIndex, mainIndex) => {
        return [this.starterMenu[starterIndex], this.mainMenu[mainIndex]];
    },
};

console.log(restaurant.order(2, 2));
```

And i got this in the Browser Console and also node js console:

**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '2')
    at Object.order (main.js:153:33)
    at main.js:157:24
```

**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrow functions do not have their own 'this' you can use a regular function declaration, see if this post helps:
[this inside object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043509/this-inside-object)

```js
const restaurant = {
    name: 'Classico Italiano',
    location: 'Via Angelo Tavanti 23, Firenze, Italy',
    categories: ['Italian', 'Pizzeria', 'Vegetarian', 'Organic'],
    starterMenu: ['Focaccia', 'Bruschetta', 'Garlic Bread', 'Caprese Salad'],
    mainMenu: ['Pizza', 'Pasta', 'Risotto'],
    order: function(starterIndex, mainIndex) {
        return [this.starterMenu[starterIndex], this.mainMenu[mainIndex]];
    },
};

console.log(restaurant.order(2, 2));
```

Comment: Dang it thank u so much i really appreciate it❤