# I'm trying to get a string element in a Javascript object to use the value from another elememt

Tags: javascript, object

I'm building a website with some rpg stat blocks for a table top role playing game I'm trying get a string element to use data from another element.
but it when I go to boot up a web browser it prints it as undefined.

These element are part of the same object.

```
        str: 18,
        proficiency: 2,
        attackroll: "",
        Attack: function() {
            this.attackroll = ((this.proficiency + Math.floor(((this.str)-10)/2)).toString());
            console.log(this.attackroll)
        },
actions:"Bite. +" + this.attackroll +  " to hit, reach 5ft, one target. Hit: 16 (3d8 + 4 piercing damage).",
```

When I go to run the HTML it prints:

Bite. +undefined to hit, reach 5ft, one target. Hit: 16 (3d8 + 4 piercing damage).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: can't really see what is going on (can't see how you are using the object) - but looks like the `Attack` property was never called to trigger setting the `attackroll` property.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["this" inside object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043509/this-inside-object)

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7043822/4476484) might help you. `this` doesn't really work with objects like how you're trying to use it. You could use a `class` instead or try building the object up over multiple steps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a class for this.

```js
class Character {
    constructor(str, proficiency) {
        this.str = str;
        this.proficiency = proficiency;
        this.attackroll = ((this.proficiency + Math.floor(((this.str)-10)/2)).toString());
        this.actions = "Bite. +" + this.attackroll +  " to hit, reach 5ft, one target. Hit: 16 (3d8 + 4 piercing damage).";
    }
    
    Attack() {
        console.log(this.attackroll)
    }
}
```

Create a new instance of the class like this:

```js
const myCharacter = new Character(18, 2);
```

and then you can access the attributes and call the functions like this:

```js
myCharacter.actions
myCharacter.Attack();
```

#### Code snippet

You can run this and see it working:

```js
class Character {
    constructor(str, proficiency) {
        this.str = str;
        this.proficiency = proficiency;
        this.attackroll = ((this.proficiency + Math.floor(((this.str)-10)/2)).toString());
        this.actions = "Bite. +" + this.attackroll +  " to hit, reach 5ft, one target. Hit: 16 (3d8 + 4 piercing damage).";
    }
    
    Attack() {
        console.log(this.attackroll)
    }
}

const myCharacter = new Character(18, 2);

console.log(myCharacter.str);
console.log(myCharacter.proficiency);
console.log(myCharacter.attackroll);
console.log(myCharacter.actions);
myCharacter.Attack();
```